# Easy way to color border/edges of 3D Cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

## Question

I am trying to give a colored 3D Cube which has a specific Color a differently colored border. The Cube uses currently a Mixed Reality Toolkit/Standard Shader by which it is colored. Now i would like to still color the cube by this shader but also color the edges of the cube in Black.

## Problem

Is there a way to do this without changing the Shader. I only found examples like the Asset [Quick Outline](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488) but they do not color all edges. Further they make the object bigger as they add the outline on the outside. I want the border to be on the "inside" of the cube so that the size stays the same.
As visual example of what i want to achive see the following images:

Example with wrong Outline (like Quick Outline):

[image: Wrong Outline Shaders]

Example with correct Outline:

[image]

Do i need to write my own shader or is there a shader which does this. Or is it even possible to do this without a specific shader with some mesh code i did not found?

Comment: Google something around "unity render wireframe", there are plenty of examples. It will require a shader, but it's not as complex as it seems

Comment: yeah that would be more "wireframe" not "outline"

Comment: The problem with "wireframe" would be that you'd also see the triangles on the sides.

Comment: @MaxPlay yeah that depends .. you can sure in the shader check for a minimum angle between faces before an edge is treated as edge which would remove the diagonals

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov I tried "wireframe" but as MaxPlay mentioned this colors the edges of all triangles, not just the visible borders. Also i would need an additional GameObject which i overlay as the wireframe shaders do not have a fill color.

Comment: @Alex you're quite picky. The "visible border" is quite a complex thing geometrically, given that all you have is a triangle mesh and a shader program that iterates plain vertrices and pixels on GPU. It's hard to achieve what you ask for without special processing like derHugo suggested. You could also consider rendering normals for the object and in a second pass sample nearby normals to deterimine if there's big enough change, thus treating it like a "visible border". Don't expect a built-in solution to exist. Maybe some Unity plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a Solution with the currently used **Mixed Reality Toolkit/Standard Shader**. There is a option called **Border Light** which creates a black/white border around the edges of my cubes.

I have attached a photo of the unity parameters for others who may also be in need of such an effect.

[image: Cube with white border]
[image: Parameters in Inspector]