# MRTK Standard Shader - Border Light Shading Off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

## Question

I am trying to give a colored 3D Cube which has a specific Color a differently colored border for my Hololens 2 application. [I now found out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77082009/13896230) that i can use the **Mixed Reality Toolkit/Standard Shader** with the **Border Light** option to color the edges of an object in white or black.

When starting Unity and looking in the scene view the cube looks correct:

[image: Cube with white Border]
[image: Parameters o Shader]

## Problem

When I start my application, the edges of the cube are incorrect in the scene/game view. The higher I make the border width, the more wrong the border is drawn (see images).

[image: Incorrect border of Cube]
[image: Incorrect border of Cube (higher width)]

I tried to change the size of the cube, but that didn't help. When i restart unity it works again until i press play - then it always gets rendered wrong. I have no idea what setting could be wrong? I assume it has something to do with the camera, but all other parameters of the shader look correct.

I am using *Unity 2022.3.8f1* and *MRTK 2.8.3.0*

Comment: I did some tests using Unity 2021.3.27 and did not reproduce your issue. Currently, the officially recommended Unity version is still Unity 2021LTS. Could you use Unity 2021LTS to test it again? Also, there are some samples about border light in **MRTK Examples package->Demos-StandardShader->MaterialGallery**, please do some tests on them. For more samples of standard shader, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/rendering/mrtk-standard-shader?view=mrtkunity-2022-05.

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT I tried Unity 2021.3.30.f1 and it works now correct. In Unity 2022.3.8f1 also the Demo (MaterialGallery) was wrong (BorderLight, Round Corners). Thanks for pointing that out.
Side Question: When would it be advisable to upgrade to a new Unity version and MRTK3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ZuochengWang-MSFT described, the problem is due to the Unity version I used. In **Unity 2022.3.8f1**, certain shader functions such as Border Light and Rounded Corner do not work correctly (see image).

[image: MaterialGallery with wrong shaders]

In the version **Unity 2021.3.30.f1** everything works correctly!